# generating ssl from pem and private key

Tags: ssl, openssl, pem, crt

I m trying to get ssl file from pem file

I tried to the following

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in C:\Users\user\Desktop\ssl\abc.pem -out C:\Users\user\Desktop\ssl\ssl.crt
```

ssl.crt is generated. But i couldnt open the generated crt file in notepad.

i think there should be a file like the followin? Am i wrong

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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mnkPIAou1Z5jJh5VkpTYghdae9C8x49OhgQ=

 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: `-outform der` instructs the output to be DER format, that is binary. You can convert it to "PEM" format ( the example you give) later, or simpler just do `-outform pem` or maybe just remove everything, PEM may be the default.

Comment: *"But i couldnt open the generated crt file in notepad."* - what you expect a __text editor__ like notepad to do with the (binary) certificate? What you are trying to achieve ultimately?

Comment: Your example is almost PEM format but not actually valid, as well as having the contents damaged, perhaps intentionally. From the name `abc.pem` quite likely is _already_ PEM format; did you look at it? Many things that read certs accept _either_ DER or PEM, but if you want to configure an SSL/TLS server you need not just an appropriate cert (which this isn't) but also a matching privatekey, and the format(s) for that depends mostly on what server (and sometimes options) you are using.